# Setting up profile for Aer V3 for Fan Control by Pherein TO SPEED up the fan

Tags: speed, fan

It is really hard to gain control above the fan speed in laptop. 
I have Acer V3-571G i-3110,Nvidia 630GT. I want to speed up a fan.

Program: http://www.ratedsearch.net/rated-file/rs5ef9b4f8hfi0#

Needs also that to work:  http://rweverything.com/download/

The example for MSI GX740:
profile

```
   [Temperatures_1]
    OS01=0x6A
    OS02=0x6B
    OS03=0x6C
    OS04=0x6D
    OS05=0x6E
    OS06=0x6F
    OS07=0x70
    OS08=
OS09=
OS10=

[FanSpeeds_1]
OS01=0x72
OS02=0x73
OS03=0x74
OS04=0x75
OS05=0x76
OS06=0x77
OS07=0x78
OS08=
OS09=
OS10=

[Temperatures_2]
OS01=0x82
OS02=0x83
OS03=0x84
OS04=0x85
OS05=0x86
OS06=0x87
OS07=0x88
OS08=
OS09=
OS10=

[FanSpeeds_2]
OS01=0x8A
OS02=0x8B
OS03=0x8C
OS04=0x8D
OS05=0x8E
OS06=0x8F
OS07=0x90
OS08=
OS09=
OS10=
```

settings for agressive fan

```
Profile Name: Aggressive
[Temperatures_1]
>WEC 0x6A 0x35
>WEC 0x6B 0x3C
>WEC 0x6C 0x43
>WEC 0x6D 0x4A
>WEC 0x6E 0x51
>WEC 0x6F 0x5A
>WEC 0x70 0x6E
----
[FanSpeeds_1]
>WEC 0x72 0x28
>WEC 0x73 0x2D
>WEC 0x74 0x32
>WEC 0x75 0x35
>WEC 0x76 0x3C
>WEC 0x77 0x40
>WEC 0x78 0x4C
----
[Temperatures_2]
>WEC 0x82 0x35
>WEC 0x83 0x3C
>WEC 0x84 0x43
>WEC 0x85 0x4A
>WEC 0x86 0x51
>WEC 0x87 0x5A
>WEC 0x88 0x6E
----
[FanSpeeds_2]
>WEC 0x8A 0x28
>WEC 0x8B 0x2D
>WEC 0x8C 0x32
>WEC 0x8D 0x35
>WEC 0x8E 0x3C
>WEC 0x8F 0x40
>WEC 0x90 0x4C
----
>RwExit
```

Comment: might help to link the program in question

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Added download links.